# Is it possible to use roslaunch without starting roscore?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is the setup

I have an application running on a Jetson nano which is started with roslaunch.  I am running ROS-Melodic on that computer and I consider it as the ROS_MASTER_URI. As the application is using roslaunch, roscore is started as well.

On my laptop I want to start another application which is using roslaunch as well, and this is the beginning of my problem, because per default roslaunch starts a roscore on the local machine.

Is it possible to prevent the start of roscore with roslaunch?

Thank you for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356754/is-it-possible-to-use-roslaunch-without-starting-roscore?/) by [fabriceN](https://answers.ros.org/users/31629/fabricen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2020-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[link text](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) Have a look at the link. I use ROS_MASTER_URI and ROS_HOSTNAME placed in the bashrc´s . roslaunch only starts a roscore if there is none running.

---

Originally posted by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) with karma: 574 on 2020-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fabriceN](https://answers.ros.org/users/31629/fabricen/) on 2020-07-09**:
@Dragonslayer, on the jetson nano I setup (for instance)
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.10.10.10 and ROS_HOSTNAME=10.10.10.10
I start roslaunch appli appli.launch
Now on my Laptop i will setup:
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.10.10.10 and ROS_HOSTNAME=10.10.10.9
and what I want is that the application spawn by roslaunch  get topics from the application on the jetson nano. Unfortunately when I run roslaunch on my laptop, ROS is starting a roscore locally which means that I cannot access the topics published by the application of the jetson nano. Do you know if there is any possibility to prevent roslaunch to start a roscore?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2020-07-09**:
If `ROS_MASTER_URI` and `ROS_IP`/`ROS_HOSTNAME` are set correctly, then the answer from @Dragonslayer is correct, `roslaunch` on the computer that shouldn't run master should not start a master. To answer the question in the comment above, you could try adding `--wait` to your `roslaunch` call to cause it to wait for a master before launching

**Comment by [Dragonslayer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38812/dragonslayer/) on 2020-07-09**:
@fabriceN I came across lots of people with issues getting this to run. For some a simple restart did the trick. Iam also not sure if launching the core on the jetson and after that "setup:" the stuff on the laptop might be the problem, could be the the roscore start sents a trigger or something like that, that is missed if you only setup the laptop after the core start etc. Of course turning off the firewalls (or preparing them in a way that data can flow) is absolut relevant. As I mentioned I have this in my bashrc`s so it sets itself up and that works fine, also for others. Pinging works? @jarvisschultz good idea "--wait".